# Using loop-for through array to push key-values nested inside, into a different array. Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

newbie here.

I'm having trouble with a simple challenge, the goal is simple, push the sedan cars into another array, so the output when the function is called (no console.log can be used, it will be ignored) is:

`[  { type:'sedan', size: 'white'} , { type:'sedan', color:'red'}  ].`

The suggestion is to use push().

Here is my terrible code.

Any help is welcome!

```
function filterCars (cars) {
     const sedanCars = []
     const carArr = [
      { type: 'sedan', color: 'white'},
      { type: 'truck', color: 'blue'},
      { type: 'sedan', color: 'red'},
      { type: 'coupe', color: 'red'}
      ]
   
    var arrayLength = carArr.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    console.log(carArr[i]);
        
  if(carArr.type==="sedan") {
          return sedanCars.push("sedan");
        }
```

Comment: `carArr` is an array, not an object. You need to index it to access the object with a `type` property.

Comment: Why are you pushing a string onto the array? Don't you want an array of objects? It seems like you haven't really thought about this problem very much, and just wrote some random code that uses the function you were told about. You won't learn to program by trial and error.

Comment: Please check my solution(s) when you have a chance. I provided one using the `push()` method, and another using the `spread` operator (`...`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `filterCars` function and `return` do not seem all that clear to me in their function, especially since you are triggering your `return` within a `for` loop iteration.

There are several ways we can approach this…

##### Option #1. Building a `filter`-based function

```js
function getSedans(cars) {
  return cars.filter(car => car.type === 'sedan')
}
const carArr = [
  { type: 'sedan', color: 'white' },
  { type: 'truck', color: 'blue' },
  { type: 'sedan', color: 'red' },
  { type: 'coupe', color: 'red' }
];
const sedanCars = getSedans(carArr);

// including this console.log to provide the output
console.log(sedanCars);
```

##### Option #2. `filter`-based function + `push()` & spread (`...`)

If you would prefer to use this solution but also use push, you could do by declaring the empty `sedanCars` array before the `carArr` and then push the results of `getSedans(carArr)` to it like this…

```js
const sedanCars = [],
      carArr = [ /* cars here */ ];
sedanCars.push(...getSedans(carArr));
```

You can see that in action here:

```js
function getSedans(cars) {
  return cars.filter(car => car.type === 'sedan')
}
const sedanCars = [],
      carArr = [
        { type: 'sedan', color: 'white' },
        { type: 'truck', color: 'blue' },
        { type: 'sedan', color: 'red' },
        { type: 'coupe', color: 'red' }
      ];
sedanCars.push(...getSedans(carArr));

// including this console.log to provide the output
console.log(sedanCars);
```

##### Option #3. `push()` method using `for..of` loop

However, this adds an extra unnecessary step by using spread. If you really prefer to use `push()`, here is a more appropriate method for using it:

```js
const sedanCars = [],
      carArr = [
        { type: 'sedan', color: 'white' },
        { type: 'truck', color: 'blue' },
        { type: 'sedan', color: 'red' },
        { type: 'coupe', color: 'red' }
      ];
for (const car of carArr) {
  if (car.type === 'sedan') sedanCars.push(car);
}

// including this console.log to provide the output
console.log(sedanCars);
```

##### Option #4. `push()` method using `forEach` method

And lastly, if you wanna get fancy, you could replace that entire `for..of` loop with a `forEach` invocation and replace the `if` statement for a short circuit, like this:

```js
carArr.forEach(car => car.type === 'sedan' && sedanCars.push(car));
```

Here is how that would look in action:

```js
const sedanCars = [],
      carArr = [
        { type: 'sedan', color: 'white' },
        { type: 'truck', color: 'blue' },
        { type: 'sedan', color: 'red' },
        { type: 'coupe', color: 'red' }
      ];
carArr.forEach(car => car.type === 'sedan' && sedanCars.push(car));

// including this console.log to provide the output
console.log(sedanCars);
```

Comment: What's the point of the spread operator in the first solution? You're just making a copy of the array returned by `filter()`

Comment: @Barmar you're absolutely right — good call-out! I refactored that to show a more appropriate scenario for the spread operator, and a separate solution to demonstrate the `forEach()`. Thanks 

Comment: Thanks Brandon!

Answer (score 0):

Since `push` is only a suggestion, I would recommend a more modern approach using the array `filter` method for this:

```js
const cars = [
  { type: 'sedan', color: 'white'},
  { type: 'truck', color: 'blue'},
  { type: 'sedan', color: 'red'},
  { type: 'coupe', color: 'red'},
];

const sedans = cars.filter(car => car.type === 'sedan');
```

The `filter` methods takes a callback function that is called on each element of the array. If it returns a truthy value then that item will be included in the resulting array.

Read more about filter on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter